# g:include vs g:render

Tags: grails, include, render

I have a question about pros and cons of g:render and g:include.
In my application I have a piece of code that shows some information that have to be repeated in some gsp, what it show depends on a little bit of logic.
I have a doubt is it better use a *g:include* or a *g:render*???
So, is it better to execute the logic on a controller that pass a model to the page that use a layout included with the g:render, or is better to put a g:include to another action in another controller in the gsp that execute the logic of that piece?
I prefer the second choice, but how much it impact on the performance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are just used in different cases.  You use `<g:include .../>` when you have a controller that is returning a piece of content that is easily embedded in multiple GSPs.  This is also useful if you have a high volume of traffic where you are actually caching at the controller level since you can eliminate a lot of overhead.

`<g:render.../>` is useful when you need modularity within your page.  Especially for AJAX calls where you may initially load one portion of the page then want to update it based on some AJAX event.

Both can be used to reuse content, and both are appropriate in the right context.

Answer (score 0):

g:render is useful while you are working on partial templates and you have the model you need etc.
However, when you need additional (or extensive) progress to pass extra, more meaningful things to your view(template), it is better to use g:include.
By using g:include you will also have a nice controller and that means much more readable code using that controller.
And there would be no performance comparison between 'passing to a controller action and render a view with doing no additional operation' and 'render a view'.